# android animate object to center of ConstraintLayout

Tags: android

In one of my layout i have this structure

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_500"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/instagram_avatar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_white_shape"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_wizard_1"
        android:tint="@color/mdtp_white"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/grey_5"
        app:civ_border_width="3dp"
        app:civ_fill_color="@color/mdtp_white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

in that i want to animate moving `instagram_avatar` CircleImageView to center of ConstraintLayout, how can i calculate center of device and move to that?

for example:

```
instagram_avatar.animate().y(50f).x(50f).setDuration(5000).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                int[] location = new int[2];
                imageView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

                int imgHeight = imageView.getHeight();
                int y = location[1];


                Point point = new Point();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);


                imageView.animate()
                        .translationY((point.y) / 2f - y - imgHeight / 2f)
                        .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
                        .setDuration(5000)
                        .start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: unfortunately your code doesn't work, i think problem is `layout_constraintEnd` attribute

Comment: Thanks a lot. how can i disable back to previous position?

Comment: and each of click on imageView cause of change position

Answer (score 0):

link to explanations, where I took code from -  https://robinhood.engineering/beautiful-animations-using-android-constraintlayout-eee5b72ecae3

```
        val autoTransition = AutoTransition()
        autoTransition.duration = 400

        val set = ConstraintSet()
        set.clone(view as ConstraintLayout)
        set.centerVertically(R.id.instagram_avatar, 0)
        set.centerHorizontally(R.id.instagram_avatar, 0)

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(view as ConstraintLayout, autoTransition)
        set.applyTo(view as ConstraintLayout)
```